# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Can't reach controller

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have been doing a project of my own, for fun, using java, javafx and scene builder. Unfortunately I have encountered an issue which i can't fix. I have an fxml file called 'Homepage' and a controller called HomepageController.
When I run the program it gives me an error 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HomepageController'.
I'm using MVC architecture, where my FXML file is in a package named 'views' and my controller is in a different package named 'controllers'
I have been searching for similar issues but couldn´t find a solution. Can anybody help?

The FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="HomepageController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.2505567928730512, 0.7505567928730512" focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <items>
            <AnchorPane>
               <children>
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" minWidth="60.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="&#10;" text="Tournament" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="false">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" fx:id="x1" />
                     </font>
                     <textFill>
                        <Color blue="0.624" green="0.624" red="0.624" fx:id="x2" />
                     </textFill>
                  </Label>
                  <Button layoutX="58.0" layoutY="553.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addTournament" text="Add Tournament" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <ScrollPane prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="592.0" prefWidth="430.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" font="$x1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" style="&#10;" text="Teams" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="$x2" wrapText="false" />
                        <Button layoutX="180.0" layoutY="553.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addTeam" text="Add Team" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <AnchorPane>
               <children>
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" font="$x1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" style="&#10;" text="Players" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="$x2" wrapText="false" />
                  <Button layoutX="74.0" layoutY="553.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addPlayer" text="Add Player" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
      <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

The controller

```java
package controllers;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class HomepageController {

    @FXML
    private Font x1;

    @FXML
    private Color x2;

    @FXML
    void addPlayer(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Add Player Button");
    }

    @FXML
    void addTeam(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Add Team Button");
    }

    @FXML
    void addTournament(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Add Tournament Button");
    }

}
```

And this is what show's up in the console

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/joao/eclipse-workspace/Virtual%20Tournament/bin/views/Homepage.fxml:14

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HomepageController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Well, I'm just a JavaFX novice, but I'm not surprised, you don't have a controller named `HomepageController`. You only have `controllers.HomepageController`.

Comment: As @Tom said you should modify your fxml file with `fx:controller="controllers.HomepageController"`

Comment: That's right. It asks for the package aswell. i changed the controller to controllers.HomepageController and it ran. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using FXML files, the FXML file needs to know the file of the controller AND the package name.

`<VBox prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.HomepageController">`

Comment: The combination of package name and class name called *"fully qualified (class) name"*.